# System.Exception: The file 'E:\Roaming\sfddf.pdf' already exists. If you contact support, please provide the technical details

Tags: c#, plugins, workflow

I'm getting the above error. The requirement is

- Get the SSRS Configuration record and Generate the token.
- Read the workflow input parameters and Render report
- Attach to email if Email reference not null as per the format input. Set the Output parameter EmailAttachmentid
- Attach to Notes if the input parameter is true, as per the format.

Code

```
 public static void StartMethod(IOrganizationService service)
    {           
        var reportid = "25C85C59-7D04-E711-80E6-00155DB8652A";
        ColumnSet rclms = new ColumnSet("reportnameonsrs", "languagecode", "defaultfilter");
        Entity report = service.Retrieve("report", new Guid(reportid), rclms);
        byte[] rendered = RenderSSRSReport(report, "PDF", "",tracingservice, context);
        string Bace64String = Convert.ToBase64String(rendered);
        System.IO.FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"E:\Roaming\file.pdf", FileMode.CreateNew);
        System.IO.BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);
        writer.Write(rendered, 0, rendered.Length);
        writer.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Use CreateOrOpen or delete the existing file before overwriting it with the same name.

Comment: @John hi john the error is file is already existed but there is no file is creating in my local system. I'm running this through custom workflow so I think i need to modify the path differently but I don't know how to give.

Comment: You forgot to `Dispose` the `stream`.

Comment: @mjwills how to dispose the stream?

Comment: @sreeman I'd suggest googling for "how to dispose a stream".

Comment: @mjwills I tried but there is no change in my result

Comment: Please show us your current code, so we can be confident you applied the changes that @John and I suggested.